# Validation Issue PHP

Tags: php, validation

I have a form which I am validating on client side for user interaction and server side for data integrity. Now on client side when an input is wrong or empty I show an alert box which shows the error message.Now on the server Side should I run the same checks again(eg Firstname can only be alphabets) or what else should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you should - what if the User has Java Script Disabled?

If you are going to omit the validation anywhere - you should omit it client side.

Comment: The other thing you are going to want to think about on the server side is cleansing your data to prevent SQL injection attacks. You dont want to leave gaping security holes like this open - just becuase its a bit more effort, especially when they are so easy to deal with :-)

Answer (score 6):

This is a typical form validation problem

1. on the client (browser), you check the form (e.g. via JavaScript) to kindly help the user quickly (no server exchange) to fill the form *correctly*.
2. However, the user may input a mistake / challenge your JavaScript / edit your page / bypass the page protections and controls... so you *never* trust the user input and *must* always double check server side the input coming from the user/browser/script, i.e. with PHP.

Comment: Ok. So here is the case , I have a form on page 1 which is posting data to page 2 . Now if there's an error in the input and I do an echo to tell user about the mistake. it would automatically come into page2. How to fix this?

Comment: You have send Page 2 the data, so you need Page 2 to display the form again, populating the inputs with the data already submitted, and flag the relevant error.

Comment: Usually between page1 and page2, some PHP script is executed (i.e. PHP *triggers* the load of page2). So in your PHP script, if there is an error, you should send the user back to page1, with, for instance, a parameter ERROR set to a message that will be displayed to the user. And in page1 you check if the parameter is set. E.g. http://myserver.com/page1.php?ERROR=Please+enter+phone+number+correctly . This is just an example, there are many other ways, like send user back to page1, redisplay the FORM with the parameters from users, and the missing one in **red** with an error message.

Answer (score 5):

Of course. You must. Javascript validation is only relevant for user experience, but anybody can send invalid data to your server with small knowledge.

Comment: The easiest way you can try it: turn off javascript in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes and Yes - of course!

If you have the time i would encourage to implement at least the following:

1. Make use of up-to-date Browser Form Validation feautures http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html#validation
2. (if 1 is not possible and in addition) Run your JS Validation on the submit event
3. Run a Check and Pass Errors along to the View in your Application Logic
4. Do a Check and Throw Exceptions in your Bussiness Logic

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** perform validation server-side to begin with, and only afterwards do client-side validation. (Or vice-versa, as long as server-side validation is implemented).

If it is important to you that first name should only contain alpha characters, then yes you should implement that validation server-side. (off-topic: You shouldn't limit name to alpha characters.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just as you've written: check again, because client validation can be avoided. Do the same check as you do at clientside validation and output errors if input isn't valid.

And remember: filter&validate input, escape output.

Comment: what do you mean by escape output?

Comment: That's the web app principle, even though you filter and validate the input, you should still escape the data when you output it to prevent xss attacks. You never know what you might have missed at filtering and validating.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how much validation you have on Client side, you must do so at Server side also. Any malicious user can by pass the client side validation and send data to server.

One good practice is to use the server side script for client side validation using Ajax, unless that data being checked is too heavy, which isn't usually the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** validate all data on the server side.

User-side validation is part of providing a better user experience as pinusnegra stated; it also helps keep resource usage on the server lower (since many of the requests validation is done on the client side). However, it does not substitute for server validation if a user has javascript disabled or is maliciously trying to tamper with your web application.

Do this little experiment: navigate to one of your forms where you're applying javascript validation and then:

1. save the source (view source option of your browser) to a local file
2. change the form action url to the correct one (with full domain instead of just /path/to/my/serverscript/)
3. remove all the javascript validation
4. submit erroneous data (i.e. only numbers on First Name)

After that, you now have faulty data in your database. I hope that clears the point.